# objective is to post the data in variable 'data' to endpoint called '/post_data' and then write that to an excel file. Facing connection error 10061

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests

objective is to post the data in variable 'data' to endpoint called '/post_data' and then write that complete data to an excel file and then make that file available for download but i am facing . Facing connection error 10061.

**Error details below:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 1063, in main
    cli.main()
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 911, in run_command
    raise e from None
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 897, in run_command
    app = info.load_app()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 312, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\app.py", line 47, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\pavankumar4\PycharmProjects\APICalls\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /post-data (Caused by NewConnection
Error('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000112A06C69D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be m
ade because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

I am unable to pass the 'data' variable as input to '/post_data'. stuck here

**Code:**

````
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request,render_template,send_file
import json
from openpyxl import Workbook
import requests



app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
#app = Flask(__name__)


data = {
    "HeaderInfo": {
        "ProcessAreaId": "ENG",
        "DataSetName": "TEST_ENG",
        "CountryKey": "US",
        "NumOfRecords": "5",
        "Entity": "8700",
        "EngmtStartDate": "",
        "EngmtEndDate": "",
        "EngmtType": "ZTMR"
    },
    "ClientSet": [
        {
            "ClientNum": ""
        },
        {
            "ClientNum": ""
        }
    ],
    "PartnerFuncSet": [
        {
            "PartnerType": "Z3",
            "PartnerNum": "123456"
        },
        {
            "PartnerType": "Z4",
            "PartnerNum": "123456"
        }
    ]
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
url = "http://localhost:5000/post-data"

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
requests.post()
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Data posted successfully!")
else:
    print("Error posting data: {}".format(response.status_code))


@app.route("/post_data", methods=["POST"])
def post_data():
    # Get the data from the request
    data = request.get_json()
    print('data in post data', data)

    # Create a new Excel workbook
    workbook = Workbook()

    # Create a new worksheet
    worksheet = workbook.active

    # Write the data to the worksheet
    worksheet.append([
        "HeaderInfo",
        "ClientSet",
        "PartnerFuncSet"
    ])

    for key, value in data.items():
        if key == "HeaderInfo":
            worksheet.append([key, value])
        elif key == "ClientSet":
            for client in value:
                worksheet.append([client["ClientNum"]])
        elif key == "PartnerFuncSet":
            for partner in value:
                worksheet.append([partner["PartnerType"], partner["PartnerNum"]])

    # Save the workbook
    workbook.save("data.xlsx")

    return "Data posted successfully!"




@app.route('/download_excel')
def download_excel():
    excel_file_path = r'file_paths/final_data.xlsx'
    return send_file(excel_file_path, as_attachment=True)


@app.route('/display_data')
def display_data():
    df = pd.read_excel(r'file_paths/final_data.xlsx')
    rows = df.to_dict('records')

    # Get the column names
    columns = df.columns.tolist()
    #print('columns', columns)
    return render_template(r'table.html', columns=columns, rows=rows)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template(r'index.html')


# result = data_init()
# print('result', result)
# je = json_endpoint(result)
# print("JE", je)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port =5000, debug=True)


# stored_data = {}
#
# def data_init():
#     Process_area_flag = input("Please enter the process area")
#     Default_records_flag = int(input("Please enter 1 for Default config_records else 0"))
#     Current_date = input("Please enter required Currentdate(mm/dd/yyyy) else enter 0 if default")
#     Finished_date = input("Please enter required Finisheddate(mm/dd/yyyy) else enter 0 if default")
#     Description_flag = input('Enter Description for RANDOM_TEXT else press enter key :')
#     Number_of_Records = int(input("Please enter number of records to be generated"))
#     VBUKR= input("Enter values of VBUKR's  or else press '0' to load random records")
#     POST1 = input('Enter value of POST1 or else press enter key')
#     PLFAZ= input('Enter value of PLFAZ or else press enter key')
#     PLSEZ= input('Enter value of PLSEZ or else press enter key')
#     PRART= input('Enter value of PRART or else press enter key')
#     ZZCRMOPP = input('Enter value of ZZCRMOPP or else press enter key')
#     ZZ_CLIENT = input('Enter value of ZZ_CLIENT or else press enter key')
#     input_data_dict = {
#         'Process_area_flag': Process_area_flag,
#         'Default_records_flag': Default_records_flag,
#         'Current_date': Current_date,
#         'Finished_date': Finished_date,
#         'Number_of_Records': Number_of_Records,
#         'random_state': 0,
#         'Description': Description_flag,
#          'POST1':POST1,
#          'VBUKR': VBUKR,
#          'PLFAZ': PLFAZ,
#          'PLSEZ':PLSEZ,
#          'PRART':PRART,
#         'ZZCRMOPP':ZZCRMOPP,
#          'ZZ_CLIENT':ZZ_CLIENT,
#
#
#     }
#     input_data_dict['random_state'] = random.randint(1, 200000)
#
#
#     json_ui = json.dumps(input_data_dict)
#     return json_ui
#
#
# def json_endpoint(result):
#     # json_extracted_data = jsonify(json.loads(result))
#     extracted_json = json.loads(result)
#     # print('JSON ED',json_extracted_data)
#     # print('json ed', extracted_json)
#     return extracted_json

```

`
````

Answer (score 0):

Sending request to your server in the server file is not a good idea.
Create another file after running the server instead.

Also you misspelled the post_data part. You wrote post-data instead.

```
import json,requests


data = {
    "HeaderInfo": {
        "ProcessAreaId": "ENG",
        "DataSetName": "TEST_ENG",
        "CountryKey": "US",
        "NumOfRecords": "5",
        "Entity": "8700",
        "EngmtStartDate": "",
        "EngmtEndDate": "",
        "EngmtType": "ZTMR"
    },
    "ClientSet": [
        {
            "ClientNum": ""
        },
        {
            "ClientNum": ""
        }
    ],
    "PartnerFuncSet": [
        {
            "PartnerType": "Z3",
            "PartnerNum": "123456"
        },
        {
            "PartnerType": "Z4",
            "PartnerNum": "123456"
        }
    ]
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
url = "http://localhost:5000/post_data"
#Fixed the URL
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)


if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Data posted successfully!")
else:
    print("Error posting data: {}".format(response.status_code))
```

Even tho your code does not work.

```
ValueError: Cannot convert {'ProcessAreaId': 'ENG', 'DataSetName': 'TEST_ENG', 'CountryKey': 'US', 'NumOfRecords': '5', 'Entity': '8700', 'EngmtStartDate': '', 'EngmtEndDate': '', 'EngmtType': 'ZTMR'} to Excel
```

I hope this answer helped!